# What is the significance of class data type in java?

Tags: java, types

Noob question.

I have been programming at basic level for quite a while but I have trouble understanding class data type.

when we say `int a = 9;`
it means a is of data type int meaning it can contain only integers.

like wise for String, boolean, double, float etc.

But consider the following code:

```
Class Node {

Node next = null;
int data;

public Node(int d){ data = d; }

void append(int d)
    {
        blah blah blah
        ..............
    }
}
```

What does `Node next = null;` mean? I can understand the effort to create an object with

```
Node next = new Node();
```

and then try to manipulate the next object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code:

```
Node next = null;
```

declares a variable of type `Node`. As `Node` is a class, the value of `next` is always a reference - either to an object of type `Node` or a subclass, or the `null` reference which doesn't refer to any object at all... and in this case the variable starts off with a value of `null`.

It's really important to understand that the value of `next` is *never* a `Node` object itself... it's only ever a reference. So suppose we have:

```
Node next = new Node(10);
Node foo = next;
```

Here, `next` and `foo` are separate variables, each with independent values... but we've assigned the value of `next` as the initial value of `foo`, which means they both refer to the same object. So if we print out `foo.data`, it will be 10.

I like to think of variables as pieces of paper - and in the case of variables of reference types, what's written on the piece of paper is the address of a house, or the word "null". If two pieces of paper have the same address written on them, they refer to the same house - but the two pieces of paper themselves are independent. Changing the *value* of one variable (crossing out the current address and writing another one) doesn't change anything about the other variable... but changes to the *house itself* (e.g. painting a door red) are visible whichever piece of paper you use to get there.

Note that in your question, you've lumped `String` in with `int`, `double` and `boolean`... but whereas `int`, `double` and `boolean` are *primitive* types (where the value of a variable is simply the data itself - the number etc), `String` is a class, so it's a reference type. The value of a string variable isn't the text itself, but a reference.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
Node next = null;
```

means that you define a variable `next` which holds only references to objects of type (the class) `Node`. Additionally you initialize it with the `null` value which means `no object created yet`.

Those variables actually hold references to objects and `null` is a special value valid only for objects which indicates that your variable is empty. This something like `next.append()` will fail with a nullpointer exception if `next` is still `null`.

Comment: No, `next` doesn't hold *objects* at all. It holds *references*, and `null` is a reference which doesn't refer to any object. There's no such thing as an "empty" variable - the variable has a well-defined value, it's the null reference.

Comment: I still dislike the idea that a variable is "empty" if the value is null. It's a perfectly valid value, it takes the same amount of space etc - it just refers to no object. In particular, it's worth noting that "definitely assigned, and the value is null" is *very* different from a variable which *isn't* definitely assigned yet.

Answer (score 0):

`Node next = null` means that this variable is initialized with null value, and doesn't point to any memory location.

So there isn't yest added the next "neighbor" node.

Comment: No, it *is* initialized... with the `null` value. The *variable* has a storage location, but its *value* (null) doesn't refer to any particular object.

Comment: Yes, that's better. I think it's worth going into a bit more detail about exactly what that means (as per my answer) but at least it's accurate now :)

Comment: it is debatable whether a Java reference variable **ever** really "points to a memory location".  (I know of one JVM implementation in which references were not implemented as pointers at all!)

Comment: @Stephen C - could you please expand your explanation ? I am studying now this language, and it's interesting for me.

Answer (score 0):

Node next = null; is a sort of pointer to a NodeObject. It's like declaring a variable not still initialized. 
In this case the object will probably be instantiated later.
If you put an already existing object to a null value, if there aren't other references to the same object, then the garbage collector deletes it.

> I have been programming at basic level for quite a while but I have trouble understanding class data type.
>   when we say int a = 9; it means a is of data type int meaning it can contain only integers.
>   like wise for String, boolean, double, float etc.

Pay attention that int and Integer are different in Java. int is a primitive type and it isn't an object. Integer is an object you can instantiate with new operator.